# Java store number as String in excel

Tags: java, string, excel, csv, numeric

Good day,

I have a java web application which allow user to download some data in csv format.

Everything is fine unless I have numeric data but start with 0, for example `010`.

I wish to store `010` correctly into the csv file, but it will auto change to `10`.

In my java code, I tried to append `'` in front of the number, but it will store to `'010` instead of `010`

```
data.alignCenter().text( "'010" ); \\ data is my TableBuilder object.
```

Kindly advise.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Hi @Natecat, done edit my question. If u need further info, please let me know.

Comment: Why can't you just get rid of the extra quote

Comment: What library are you using? Are you using Apache POI or jexcel?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you are looking to store the number in string format. In Excel I stored the number's `10` as string in excel by specifying `'010` and saved the document as CSV. As soon as I saved the document to CSV, the formatting information got lost and the data got stored as `010`.

Once I open the CSV file in excel **directly**, the data gets auto changed to `10`. I did a test with a text file just specifying `'10` but the when I see the data in excel it gets transformed to some wierd text. So I do not have the leading `'` character when saving numbers with leading 0's. **SO, DO NOT OPEN THE CSV FILE DIRECTLY WITH EXCEL!**

Here is a [link](http://www.upenn.edu/computing/da/bo/webi/qna/iv_csvLeadingZeros.html) that details how to keep leading zeroes in excel.

Steps that will be useful borrowed from the page:

> 1. Open a new worksheet in Excel (see below for Excel screenshots.)
> 2. Open the **Data tab**
> 3. Click on the **From text** button in the **Get External Data** section
> 4. Select your CSV file to import
> 5. Select the **"Delimited"** radio button -- **Text Import Wizard, Step 1** determines that your data is delimited
> 6. Click **Next**
> 7. Check **"Comma"** as a delimiter (column dividers will appear in preview)-- **Step 2** lets you set delimiters
> 8. Click **Next**
> 9. Highlight the column(s) with leading zeros in **Step 3**
> 10. Mark those columns format as **"text"** by clicking the radio button in the **Column Data Format section**.  `NOTE: You will need to do this for each column where the data contains leading zeros.`
> 11. Click **Finish**
> 12. The leading zeros will still be there in the new worksheet with the imported data.

Comment: +1. Ooen then file with notepad and check out the value of 010's column. Probably is going to be as you expect. Problem is in how excel show that value.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Instead of append ' in front of the number, I append `="` in front, and `"` at behind.

This solve my problem.